# ¿Cómo almacenar las props en un array que se encuentra afuera del componente funcional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un componente que recibe unas props, lo que quiero hacer es que esas props se almacenen en un arreglo que se encuentra definido fuera del componente, pero no se como hacerlo, si alguien podría ayudarme, se lo agradecería.

Acá esta el código del componente funcional

```
const useStyles = {
    root:{
        display: 'grid',
        height: '85vh',
        gridTemplateRows: 'repeat(2, 1fr)',
    },
    child: {
        display: 'grid',
        gridRow: '1',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        '@global':{
            '*::-webkit-scrollbar':{
                display: 'none',
            }
        }   
    },
    gridList: {
        flexWrap: 'nowrap',
    },
};
```

Este es el arreglo con objetos que quiero que almacene el valor que llegue del props. se que los props que coloque en entries es incorrecto.

```
const tileData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Radiación Solar', 
        entries: props.entries,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Temperatura',
        entries: props.entries,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'TEP',
        entries: props.entries,
    },
]

function Monitorear(props) {
    return (
        <div className={props.classes.root}>
            <div className={props.classes.child} >
                <GridList className={props.classes.gridList} cols={2.2}>
                    {tileData.map(tile => (
                        <GridListTile style={{ width:'max-content', height: 'auto' }} key={tile.id} col={1} >
                            <Entrada title={tile.title}/>
                        </GridListTile>
                    ))}
                </GridList>
            </div>
            <div style={{ gridRow: '2', }}> 
                <Salida socket={props.socket}/>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(Monitorear);
```

Comment: No termino de entender el problema. ¿Cuál es el motivo por tener ese array fuera del componente? Si necesitas tener el array en un componente padre y modificarlo en el hijo tienes la opción de tenerlo como estado en el padre y pasarle una función al hijo que modifique el array. Otra opción sería tener el array en un contexto pero si sólo hay un nivel entre componentes no creo que te merezca la pena.

Comment: si tienes razón, gracias por tu respuesta